# Docker build command is throwing error in jenkins

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

When i am running the jenkins pipline then "docker build -t " command written in jenkinsfile is giving me below the error.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fMFkm.png)

unable to prepare context: unable to evaluate symlinks in Dockerfile path: lstat /var/lib/snapd/void/Dockerfile: no such file or directory

Comment: Can you tell what is the path of your Dockerfile?

Answer (score 0):

For dockerfiles

Some information on the purpose of a dockerfile,
Docker can build images automatically by reading the instructions from a Dockerfile. A Dockerfile is a text document that contains all the commands a user could call on the command line to assemble an image. Using docker build users can create an automated build that executes several command-line instructions in succession.

More information with the arguments and how to use them in the Docker documentation,
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/

For `Docker build`

Description
Build an image from a Dockerfile

Usage
`docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -`

Extended description
The docker build command builds Docker images from a Dockerfile and a “context”. A build’s context is the set of files located in the specified PATH or URL. The build process can refer to any of the files in the context. For example, your build can use a COPY instruction to reference a file in the context.

The URL parameter can refer to three kinds of resources: Git repositories, pre-packaged tarball contexts and plain text files.

More information from the Docker documentation,
https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/build/

If you docker build successfully build after, but Jenkins stil reports the same error as before then,

you need to check the filepaths for `/var/lib/snapd/void/Dockerfile` on the Jenkins server running the job. In addition the jenkins build error, which reports the location, `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/docExp` for the symlinks and the permissions which needs to be checked, for you to not receive any errors.

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply..but I didn't understand  I am new to this

Comment: I was watching a video about kubernetes before on YouTube, I see a Docker video by the same channel, TechWorld by Nana, for Docker, this should help you understand better, https://youtu.be/3c-iBn73dDE

Answer (score 0):

`docker build [OPTIONS] PATH | URL | -`

in your case `OPTIONS` - `-t <tag>`(did you want add tag?)
`PATH` - folder with context which be passed to build process, must be exist

commonly you enter to directory to your folder with context and write something like:
`docker build ./`

it means that docker get current dir and pass as context
and `Dockerfile` must be exist in current folder

but you can pass in [OPTIONS] `-f /path/to/Dockerfile`

Comment: I did what you have mentioned but still getting the same error:- "unable to prepare context"                             Thanks for your early reply

Comment: try to enter to you work dir with Dockerfile and do `docker build ./`

Comment: I am writing these commands in Jenkinsfile . And I did use this command too...but getting the same issue. I watched lot of video don't know what am I doing wrong

Comment: Hi,I just reinstalled the docker and now it's working properly. Thanks for your suggestions.